# enable_if works with gcc but not with clang and msvc

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, default-value, class-template

I learnt about the SFINAE principle and its various uses. Then I wrote the following program that compiles with gcc but not with msvc and clang. [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8eP8xTdeq).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> class Container {
    public:

        template<typename U = T> 
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>> foo(const T&)
        {

        }
};

template<typename T>
void func(T&& callable)
{
    Container<int> c;
    (c.*callable)(4);
}
int main(){

    //works with gcc but not with clang and msvc
    func(&Container<int>::foo); 
}
```

As we can see the above program works with gcc but not with clang and msvc and I don't know which compiler is right here. So is this program well-formed or ill-formed etc.

Comment: The problem isn't about `enable_if`. Change it to `void` and you should get the same errors.

Comment: Cool. Works ok if explicitly specialize `foo<int>` at the point where a pointer to the `foo` is taken. Also, it's either member functions are automatically "skipped" when not used so you don't need to disable them, or there are more than one such function and all-but-one are disabled for each "taking of a pointer", but then you still have to disambiguate somehow which function you're interested in when taking a pointer to it. Do you have a use-case?

Comment: The program is well-formed due to [CWG 2608](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2608.html).

Comment: BTW, your `enable_if` usage is wrong: instantiating `Container<char>` would produce hard error, you need `std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U, int>>`. In C++20, a `requires(std::is_same_v<T, int>)` (and remove the template) would simplify things.

Comment: What compile error(s) did you receive from clang and msvc?

Answer (score 9):

This is [CWG 2608](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2608.html) and the program is **well-formed**.

> If all of the template arguments can be deduced **or obtained from default template-arguments, they may all be omitted**; in this case, the empty template argument list <> itself may also be omitted.

(emphasis mine)

Note the added part which makes `func(&Container<int>::foo);` well-formed **as the template argument for `U` can be obtained from the default template argument and hence it may be omitted which implies that the empty template argument list `<>` itself may also be omitted**. Thus, gcc is standard conformant.

Here is the clang bug:

[Clang rejects valid program with default argument](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/59200)

Here is the msvc bug:

[MSVC rejects valid program with default argument](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-rejects-valid-program-with-default/10213494)