# class template empty argument list

Tags: c++, c++17

I understand in `C++17`, the following syntax is allowed (omitting the argument list).

```
template<typename T = int>
struct foo {
    using type = T;
};

int main() {
    foo f1; // compiles 
    foo<> f2; // compiles
}
```

Why is the following not supported? Why can I omit the argument list when declaring an instance, but not when accessing a member type?

```
int main() {
    foo::type t1; // fails to compile
    foo<>::type t2; // compiles
}
```

Comment: Looks like [CWG 2608](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2608.html)? See dupe: [enable_if works with gcc but not with clang and msvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74573307/enable-if-works-with-gcc-but-not-with-clang-and-msvc)

Comment: @JasonLiam I don't understand how this is a duplicate. In the example you provided, the program is well formed if they omit the empty argument list. In the example I provided, the program is not well formed. I do not believe this answers my question. Thank you for the information, however.

Comment: @JasonLiam This question is about class template argument deduction, which should not be a duplicate.

Comment: I am saying that `foo::type t1;` is/should be well-formed due to cwg 2608.

Comment: @JasonLiam This fails with both `gcc 12` and `clang 15` using `C++17`

Comment: @JasonLiam I think it's a different story; gcc doesn't work with it either.

Comment: @Jaan Yes, it fails with both. So both looks nonconformant.

Comment: @JasonLiam It doesn't feel right to mark this as a duplicate if the original and duplicate have different behaviour.

Comment: @JasonLiam The statement in standard is specified for function template specializations, I don't think it's applied for class template too..

Comment: @JasonLiam: I don't buy that CWG 2608 applies here. That's talking about function template argument deduction. Does it apply to CTAD? Does CTAD even apply to constructs like `foo::type`? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name `foo` is the name of a template, not the name of a type. A template is a grammatical construct which generates a variable, function, or type, based on a set of arguments and some prototype (the template definition). That is, a template can *generate* a type, but the template itself is not a type.

`foo` is a template. `foo<int>` is a type, generated from applying `int` to the parameters of the template `foo`. `foo<>` is also a type, applying no arguments to the parameters of the template `foo`. But `foo` is just the name of a template.

However, there are certain places where the name of a template for a type can be used in place of a type name. For example, if you're in the definition of `foo` and refer to `foo` (such as specifying the name of the constructor or a function parameter or the like), you are referring to the specific `foo` being instantiated with a specific set of template parameters.

One other place where `foo` can be used in place of a type name is when creating an object (such as with `foo f1;`. This uses a process called class template argument deduction, which takes the arguments passed to the constructor and applies them through various processes to figure out what the template arguments should be. `foo f1;` works because that grammar triggers CTAD, and no arguments given means no template arguments are deduced, but `foo`'s parameters are all defaulted, so that's fine.

`foo::type` is not grammar which triggers CTAD. Since CTAD is based on arguments to constructors (even if you don't pass any), CTAD only applies to grammar which creates an object from that template. There is no object being created, so CTAD doesn't apply. So `foo` just names a template, and a template can't have `::` applied to it.